# Не получается залить проект на GitHub из AndroidStudio

Tags: android, android-studio, github

При попытке залить проект `VCS ->Import into Version Control -> Share project on GitHub` получаю это:

```
Can't finish GitHub sharing process
Successfully created project 'MyProjectName' on GitHub, but initial commit failed: *** Please tell me who you are. Run git config --global user.email "you@example.com" git config --global user.name "Your Name" to set your account's default identity. Omit --global to set the identity only in this repository. fatal: empty ident name (for  ) not allowed during executing git -c core.quotepath=false commit -m "Initial commit" --
```

Вопрос: что с этим нужно делать, раньше у меня подобной проблемы не было!

Comment: Кто вы? Вы не прошли commit. Всё же подробно описано. Там целая инструкция, что делать.

Comment: Добавь коммент к тому, что выкладываешь (поле Commit Message), и проверь, когда делаешь коммит, указаны ли у тебя в поле Author данные о тебе ))

Comment: через консоль что  то не очень получается, а указав поле Author и Commit Message - ничего не изменилось

Comment: @KirillStoianov, сделай все вручную через терминал (или командную строку, если на винде). Так меньше геморроя.

Comment: так и сделал,  все ок, спс)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Открой Terminal внизу 
и вот тебе первоначальная [настройка](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v1/%D0%92%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B0-Git) от Git'a

Начиная от и вперед

- `$ git config --global user.name "Твоё имя"`
- `$ git config --global user.email твоя почта`